# why thems go up when entering the text in text field?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jqm .Actually I open the pop up screen on button click .I am facing a problem my them goes up while entering the text.Here is my code..

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/7JqRG/

```
 <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
            <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Cases</h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" id="headerButtons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                <a href="" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup"id="Edit" data-position-to="window">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
            </ul>
            <!-- **************Case Information Pop up Start*******************-->
            <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" autocorrect="off">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="caseDate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <input name="caseDate" id="caseDate" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h" >
                           <!--input name="mydate2" id="mydate2" type="date" data-role="datebox" class="caseDate_h" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/-->
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Case Notes :</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please + button on header .Pop up open fill the text black them goes up?

Comment: are u testing this on a device or on desktop?

Comment: checking the fiddle link in chrome, and it works fine.

Comment: device same in Ipad and tablet ..

Comment: @sheetal working fine on chrome .But problem is on device .Both in IOS and Android device..

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213659/1771795

Comment: Please check first my issue in ipad or tablet ..This is not my answer

Comment: Please do *not* post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer..
[window.resize due to virtual keyboard causes issues with jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879857/window-resize-due-to-virtual-keyboard-causes-issues-with-jquery-mobile)

```
1) Go into jquery.mobile-1.x.x.js

2) Find $.mobile = $.extend() and add the following attributes:

last_width: null,
last_height: null,
3) Modify getScreenHeight to work as follows:

getScreenHeight: function() {
    // Native innerHeight returns more accurate value for this across platforms,
    // jQuery version is here as a normalized fallback for platforms like Symbian

    if (this.last_width == null || this.last_height == null || this.last_width != $( window ).width())
    {
        this.last_height = window.innerHeight || $( window ).height();
        this.last_width = $(window).width();
    }
    return this.last_height;
}
```