# How to handle them jump out(while keyboard open) in query mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am facing one problem actually my them goes up when user click on text field ?I am using query mobile 1.3.
THIS IS MY SAME PROBLEM .
[why thems go up when entering the text in text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845900/why-thems-go-up-when-entering-the-text-in-text-field?noredirect=1#comment26057215_17845900)

Solution
[jQuery Mobile Responsive Panel and Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043718/jquery-mobile-responsive-panel-and-textarea/16213659#16213659)
I use this solution but not get proper result.
Here is my mobile 1.3 js
http://jsfiddle.net/fMWnz/

In which line i should change so that it will work

```
(function(root, doc, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(["jquery"], function($) {
            factory($, root, doc);
            return $.mobile;
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(root.jQuery, root, doc);
    }
}(this, document, function(jQuery, window, document, undefined) {
    (function($) {
        $.mobile = {};
    }(jQuery));
    (function($, window, undefined) {
        var nsNormalizeDict = {};
```

Comment: Not sure why, but your Fiddle is a mess (it only shows a lot of code in the preview bit).

Comment: it is whole js.1.3.1 .js ...Jquery mobile js .1.3.1

Comment: The answer is given for 1.3.0.But i need for 1.3.1

Comment: you can check this problem on ipad or tablet .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845900/why-thems-go-up-when-entering-the-text-in-text-field?noredirect=1#comment26057215_17845900

Comment: it is hole 1.3 js..:( jquerymobile 1.3

Comment: any update.. of this question

Comment: the link I gave you should solve your problem, have you tried it?

Comment: I try that i comment in my 1.3.1 js file but it not work:(

Comment: r you sure about this solution..? here is my js ?http://jsfiddle.net/fMWnz/

Comment: @omar please update solution if you have..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer..
[window.resize due to virtual keyboard causes issues with jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879857/window-resize-due-to-virtual-keyboard-causes-issues-with-jquery-mobile)

```
1) Go into jquery.mobile-1.x.x.js

2) Find $.mobile = $.extend() and add the following attributes:

last_width: null,
last_height: null,
3) Modify getScreenHeight to work as follows:

getScreenHeight: function() {
    // Native innerHeight returns more accurate value for this across platforms,
    // jQuery version is here as a normalized fallback for platforms like Symbian

    if (this.last_width == null || this.last_height == null || this.last_width != $( window ).width())
    {
        this.last_height = window.innerHeight || $( window ).height();
        this.last_width = $(window).width();
    }
    return this.last_height;
}
```