# Phonegap 3.5 - IOS 7.1+ - Keyboard Push

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

When building and running on ios 7.1+ emulator, when I focus on an input field, the keyboard pushes up the webview, resulting in my header being pushed off-screen. I would like the header to remain fixed.

I am using jQuery mobile for the UI template-ing.

Is there any workaround or standard approach to solving this issue? Also can someone explain why this is happening?

I have spent some time looking into this and found the following two related StackOverflow questions, however the solutions did not help me solve the problem.

1. [First Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap)
2. [Second Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap)

I also tried setting the jquery mobile 'data-position="fixed"' attribute to the header but that did not work either.

Thanks!

Comment: [jQM hides toolbars on focus](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/fixedToolbar.js#L242-271).

Comment: FYI, both Related links are same.

Comment: Same issue I faced. `location.reload` is the only way to come out! :-(

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773709/cordova-phonegap-3-4-0-ios-7-1-keyboard-web-view-issue) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and my headers are in position:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

Add the `data-tap-toggle="false"`  part let me know if it works.