# IBM Worklight 6.1 - iOS 7 (iPad) WebView extending height to size of split keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, keyboard, ibm-mobilefirst

I am wondering if anyone has come across the following issue and if there is a solution for Worklight 6.1 on iOS 7.1.

When I bring up the software keyboard, it resizes the web view indefinitely.  This means that when I scroll the view, it scrolls past the body content and a black underlay is displayed.  The black section is the same height and width as the keyboard.

To reproduce: I have created a standard Worklight project and added a simple text field to the default index.html page. Focus the search field and invoke the split keyboard and then scroll the page up; you will see the black section. The page continues to scroll even after the keyboard is dismissed.

There appear to be similar posts about this defect in Cordova 3.1:

- [How to fix keyboard issues with Cordova 3.1 on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416886/how-to-fix-keyboard-issues-with-cordova-3-1-on-ios)
- [Phonegap: Keyboard changes window height in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169115/phonegap-keyboard-changes-window-height-in-ios-7)

There are various fixes proposed, and I have tried some of the simpler ones without success.  I want to know if there is an official fix in Worklight for this.  I do see there appears to be a new keyboard plugin:

http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/cordova-ios-and-ios-7-support/

Comment: Can you provide a sample Worklight project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: If you download the DST App center http://bit.ly/dstcenter you will notice the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your iPad native folder and open config.xml. In widget list, add this:

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false"/>
```