# iOS split keyboard messes up cordova webview

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, keyboard, ionic-framework

I am working on a hybrid app using Cordova and Ionic the app works fine on all iOS devices except iPad that too with split key board

The problem i face is posted [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q572453) you can see the image in the post.

I tried to do some research and found out [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7293)

Also on stack overflow I found out this preference in config [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499411/ibm-worklight-6-1-ios-7-ipad-webview-extending-height-to-size-of-split-keybo) but this is not documented neither does it work

Please help

Comment: It's not a solution (hence posting as a comment). There is a bug I agree. The best I can do is suggest always including enough padding under the last input that it cannot result in being hidden behind an unsplit keyboard and to choose a background for your app (body etc) that works with the pages where you include forms. Not great I agree.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the webView to scroll,

use this,

```
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

and in device ready,

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

Comment: The issue is not with keyboard being raised its with keyboard being split into two

Comment: Im not sure if we can check if iOS has the keyboard in split mode or normal mode. Please correct me if im wrong but when the keyboard appears, webview gets scrolled and your background that doesnt match is displayed. Only work arounds i can think is either dont let the webview scroll as i mentioned because split keyboard reveals underneath. Or as harry b mentioned above, apply a background of same color or raise the height of the container when keyboard is displayed.