# Resizing problems after using the keyboard in a Cordova app on Windows Phone

Tags: android, backbone.js, cordova, windows-phone, appframework

My app uses Cordova 3.5, Backbone JS, JQuery and Appframework (former jqMobi). After I add some data to a chat dialog by keyboard the app does not flip correct back in original view. Half of the screen is filled with a grey panel.

This works fine in android version. After changing the orientation, the view is correct again.

[image: problem]

Comment: Maybe this topic is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879857/window-resize-due-to-virtual-keyboard-causes-issues-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: have you get any solution. i  face same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Margin="1,0,0,0" in MainPage.xaml in `<my:CordovaView...>`