# To center the screen on the Input by clicking on it - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, input

When click on the Input, I want him in the center of the screen,

I use HTML5 + PhoneGap, how can I do this?

(If possible via **JS**)

Comment: center what in the center?

Comment: the center / top of screen on the input

Comment: please elaborate what object do you want to be placed in the center? Maybe put in diagrams in your post to depict what you want to achieve.

Comment: the input be in the center

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731517/phonegap-jquery-mobile-page-style-breaking-when-keyboard-is-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opened the Input in full screen div instead center him